# Firebase Authentication error with Microsoft Sign In: An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building a Flutter app that uses Firebase Authentication with the Microsoft sign in and the Google sign in . I have a master user who can create new users, and when a new user is created, their information is saved to Firestore and an account is created in Firebase Authentication with a unique UID.

Here is the code I use for Microsoft

```
@override
  Future<User?> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
    UserCredential? user;
    MicrosoftAuthProvider? microsoftProvider;

    try {
      microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
      user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) { ...
```

However, when a user tries to sign in using their Microsoft account, I sometimes get the following error message: "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."

I know that the user's email address is already associated with an account in Firebase Authentication, but the strange thing is that the account was not created using any provider. It was simply created with an email address and UID as you can see in the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4bLO.png)

I suspect that this issue is specific to Microsoft authentication, as I never had the same problem with Google authentication.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I need to ensure that the email address is associated with the correct UID in Firebase Authentication, so I can't simply create a new UID.

**What I tried : **

I tried already to remove the API authorization linked to the Microsoft account and I have the same issue.

I was also thinking linking on my app the email address to the uid by using this code :

```
// The account already exists with a different credential
        AuthCredential? pendingCredential = e.credential;

        // Link the pending credential with the existing account
        if (user != null) {
          await user.user!.linkWithCredential(pendingCredential!);
        }
```

But the user is null so it is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the user's email address is already associated with an account in Firebase Authentication, but the strange thing is that the account was not created using any provider. It was simply created with an email address and UID as you can see in the picture below.

Every account in Firebase Authentication is associated with a single email address and any number of providers. In the default setting only one account can be associated with an email address. Since there is already the account you created with that email address, you can't create another account with that email address with another provider.

If you want to allow signing in to the existing account with Microsoft too, you'll need to [link that provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking) to the existing account.

If you want to allow multiple accounts with the same email address (the one you already created, and a separate one for Microsoft sign-in) you can configure your project to allow that by selecting the <kbd>Create multiple accounts for each identity provider</kbd> option in the [Authentication settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) panel in the Firebase console

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However on the following picture, you can see the last user on the top is not linked to any provider (https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4bLO.png).

I created it using the following method : 

 `await fireauth`
                `.createUser({`
                    `email: email,`
                    `displayName: ${firstName} ${lastName},`
                `}); `

Is there a way maybe to link the uid to Microsoft using Firebase Auth Admin when creating the account?

Comment: To create a user with the Microsoft sign-in provider, they need to sign in with that provider (which happens on the client).